# Alexander Ostrowski's argument for filling the gap in Gauss's proof of the FTA

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, ho.history-overview, fields

I've read in Smale "The fundamental theorem of algebra and complexity theory" and Cain "C. F. Gauss’s Proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra"  regarding how there was a gap in Gauss's proof in his thesis that was filled by Ostrowski,  published as "Uber den ersten und vierten Gauss’schen Beweis des Fundamentalsatzes der Algebra".

There is also mention that there is an English translation in private circulation.

> **Q1:** Is there an English translation of this paper?
>   **Q2:** Is there an expository article explaining this paper in English?

Comment: Q1: as you can read in the article by Smale, prof. Horst Simon made an English translation. It does not seem available online. You might just write to him and ask  [(homepage)](http://www2.lbl.gov/Publications/Deputy-Director/bio.html), I guess many would benefit from an online translation.

Comment: I've done so, thank you for the encouragement.

Comment: Not the one you asked for but I translated [Gauss's *second* proof](http://paultaylor.eu/misc/gauss).